# Anchoring the 3D view to one object

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I saw a tutorial where he used the decimal point on the numbpad to make the 3D view screen kind of anchor to that object so when he rotated the screen it would stay on that object. I tried to do that on my laptop but I dont have a Numbpad and use the 'Emulate Numbpad' feature.
Any thoughts on how I could do this with just the laptop numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open *Blender*

Go to *Blender User Preferences* (File>User Preferences or Ctrl+Alt+U)

Go to *Input*

In the search box, type *"View Selected"*

Find the one that is *under 3D View* and is currently binded to **Numpad .**

Change that to whatever key is convenient for you.

Click *Save User Settings*

Viola.